# Cas 6.1.x OAuth client_credentials with scope

Tags: oauth-2.0, cas

It does not appear that I can setup scope in a service config for grant_type of client_credentials.

Is this possible? When requesting a token, I do get back an empty "scope" value. The only way I can get a value to appear is if I pass a query parameter of &scope=foobar. But this does not make sense that the client application is setting the scope.

I want to grant a token with permission to read from API1 and write to API2 but not read/write to API3. It seems I should be able to have a config as scope: [ "java.util.HashSet", [ "api1_read", "api2_write" ] ] basic on clientId config on the cas authorization server.

Then I would image that the resource service, when validating the token would also get a list of scopes allowed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not missing anything. This capability does not exist and could possibly be added to CAS 6.3 assuming time and sponsorship would be available. Support for scopes are only available as of this writing for OpenID Connect. For OAuth, they would need to be added to the codebase and released.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I've dug thru the code a bit, would it be possible for me to make the change and have it merged into a future release?

Comment: Absolutely! All contributions are extremely welcomed with open arms regardless of shape, size and color. You may be interested in helping with fixing typos, writing documentation, authoring test cases, developing code, squashing bugs, etc. All is welcome. See [this](https://apereo.github.io/cas/developer/Contributor-Guidelines.html) for more. Note that as of this writing, your contribution would be targetted at CAS 6.3 (currently in dev)